# TPMS Rebuild Kit - Do I need it for a normal tire change if I don't have TPMS problems?

Tags: tire-pressure-monitoring-system

I'm shopping around for new tires, and at least one vendor is adding a "TPMS Rebuild Kit" to the cart by default. For a set of 4 tires, this adds $30 to the out-the-door cost. However, the item can be removed from the cart which leads me to believe it may not really be needed.

This is the justification given for the part on the vendor's site:

> Rebuilding the valve portion of the TPMS sensor insures an air tight seal and reduces the chance of early sensor replacement due to wear and corrosion of the components exposed to the environment.

This is the first car I've had with a TPMS, and the first time I've done a four-tire replacement for it. I did have to replace one tire early on due to road damage, but don't remember any mention of "TPMS Rebuild" at the time.

Is this something that's really needed for every tire change, or should I only worry about it if I'm actually experiencing problems with the TPMS?

Comment: Some vehicles don't even have a true TPMS replacing the valve stem, but rather utilize the ABS system through the wheel speed monitor to check for a low tire. You also need to consider this prior to paying for the service.

Answer (score 3):

Things to consider when having TPMS service are the age of the sensors and the cost of replacement  without a tire purchase. Some sensors are serviceable. The valve core can be replaced along with the battery and the "O" ring. Most models have a life expectancy of 7-8 years. Talk to the tire retailer and find out what they charge for a repair with out a tire purchase. If your vehicle age is close to the sensor life expectancy you may want to consider the service. As you can imagine service on a wheel after the fact may cost $30 for a single wheel. If you are in the 2-3 year old range I would pass on the service this time . The exception to this is if you live in the rust belt and have alloy wheels that see winter a lot of road  salt. Corrosion can be an issue around the valve stem.

Answer (score 2):

It's a o-ring seal that is replaced on the inside of the rim. If your not currently having tpms problems you should be ok as long as the tire installed does not damage the sensor. Many different types are out there band type ford, and valve stem type most common. Also it will need to be calibrated or recognized by the vehicle once installed. Like on chevy front left front right etc. It's standard procedure for them to replace the seals so you don't have a problem but do you really need it. I would say no.